# Next if-else not executing

Tags: java, swing

So the background of what I am trying to accomplish. I am building a student management system that includes classes for adding students, enrolling in courses, adding grades, and displaying the student grades and course averages. What happens is when I am displaying the student grades and course averages the first course the student is enrolled in calculates just fine, doesn't matter which course it is (the first course in the list or the last course). After that, it seems that the next else-if statement doesn't execute.

Here is the code from the start. Please note that I have only included the code for the first three courses.

Arrays in the MainMenu class that is to be used as a parent class.

```
public static String[] studentFirstName = {"Wendy", "Jon"};
    public static String[] studentLastName = {"Lawrence", "Paul"};
    public static String[] studentId = {"46834", "6431"};
    public static String[] studentAge = {"43", "24"};
public static String[] courseMath = new String[10000];
    public static String[] courseEnglish = new String[10000];
    public static String[] courseHistory = new String[10000];
public static int[][] courseGradeMath = new int[3][10000];
    public static int[][] courseGradeEnglish = new int[3][10000];
    public static int[][] courseGradeHistory = new int[3][10000];
 public static int mathAverageGrade = 0;
    public static int mathAverageCount = 0;
    public static int englishAverageGrade = 0;
    public static int englishAverageCount = 0;
    public static int historyAverageGrade = 0;
    public static int historyAverageCount = 0;
```

Code in the StudentGrades class

```
if (e.getSource() == gradeGetStudentIndex) {
            //clears JLabels to display the new student's grades
            mathGrade.setText("");
            mathAverage.setText("");
            englishGrade.setText("");
            englishAverage.setText("");
            historyGrade.setText("");
            historyAverage.setText("");
            

            /*
             * When gradeGetStudentIndex button is clicked it first sets the
             * variable grStudentIndex to the index of the gradeStudentCombo.
             * This variable allows for other functions to be set or retrieved
             * to/from their corresponding arrays.
             * */
            grStudentIndex = gradeStudentCombo.getSelectedIndex();

            //calculates the personal grade and the class average for Math
            if (courseGradeMath[0][grStudentIndex] > 0) {
                /*
                 * calculates personal grade by dividing array courseGrade<course-Name>[0] by
                 * array courseGrade<course-Name>[1] at the student's index of grStudentIndex.
                 * Then sets value to <course-name>Grade JLabel.
                 * */
                mathGrade.setText(String.valueOf((courseGradeMath[0][grStudentIndex] / courseGradeMath[1][grStudentIndex])));
                /*
                 * calculates class average, by looping through the array studentFirstName
                 * and adds all grades in the courseGrade<course-name>[0] 2d array then adds
                 * all the assignment counts from courseGrade<course-name>[1] 2d array
                 * */
                for (int av = 0; av <= studentFirstName.length - 1; av++) {
                    mathAverageGrade = mathAverageGrade + courseGradeMath[0][av];
                    mathAverageCount = mathAverageCount + courseGradeMath[1][av];
                }
                /*
                 * calculates the courses average by taking the total <course-name>AverageGrade
                 * divide by the total from <course-name>AverageCount and sets the average into
                 * the variable <course-name>Average.
                 * */
                mathAverage.setText(String.valueOf(mathAverageGrade / mathAverageCount));
            } else if (courseGradeEnglish[0][grStudentIndex] > 0) {
                /*
                 * calculates personal grade by dividing array courseGrade<course-Name>[0] by
                 * array courseGrade<course-Name>[1] at the student's index of grStudentIndex.
                 * Then sets value to <course-name>Grade JLabel.
                 * */
                englishGrade.setText(String.valueOf((courseGradeEnglish[0][grStudentIndex] / courseGradeEnglish[1][grStudentIndex])));
                /*
                 * calculates class average, by looping through the array studentFirstName
                 * and adds all grades in the courseGrade<course-name>[0] 2d array then adds
                 * all the assignment counts from courseGrade<course-name>[1] 2d array
                 * */
                for (int av = 0; av <= studentFirstName.length - 1; av++) {
                    englishAverageGrade = englishAverageGrade + courseGradeEnglish[0][av];
                    englishAverageCount = englishAverageCount + courseGradeEnglish[1][av];
                }
                /*
                 * calculates the courses average by taking the total <course-name>AverageGrade
                 * divide by the total from <course-name>AverageCount and sets the average into
                 * the variable <course-name>Average.
                 * */
                englishAverage.setText(String.valueOf(englishAverageGrade / englishAverageCount));
            } else if (courseGradeHistory[1][grStudentIndex] > 0) {
                /*
                 * calculates personal grade by dividing array courseGrade<course-Name>[0] by
                 * array courseGrade<course-Name>[1] at the student's index of grStudentIndex.
                 * Then sets value to <course-name>Grade JLabel.
                 * */
                historyGrade.setText(String.valueOf((courseGradeHistory[0][grStudentIndex] / courseGradeHistory[1][grStudentIndex])));
                /*
                 * calculates class average, by looping through the array studentFirstName
                 * and adds all grades in the courseGrade<course-name>[0] 2d array then adds
                 * all the assignment counts from courseGrade<course-name>[1] 2d array
                 * */
                for (int av = 0; av <= studentFirstName.length - 1; av++) {
                    historyAverageGrade = historyAverageGrade + courseGradeHistory[0][av];
                    historyAverageCount = historyAverageCount + courseGradeHistory[1][av];
                }
                /*
                 * calculates the courses average by taking the total <course-name>AverageGrade
                 * divide by the total from <course-name>AverageCount and sets the average into
                 * the variable <course-name>Average.
                 * */
                historyAverage.setText(String.valueOf(historyAverageGrade / historyAverageCount));
            }
```

This is what I see:

[Wendy is enrolled in Math and English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdOz4.png)
[Jon is enrolled in English and History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWAzZ.png)

Comment: `if (a) {...} else if (b) {...} else if (c) {...}` are mutually exclusive: Only *one* of the blocks `{...}` will be executed. Try removing the `else`s.

Comment: I took the elses out and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Are you testing by running this within the IDE? If so, have you checked console output?  Look at both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Use _if-statements_ rather than _else-if statements_.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger? You can set a breakpoint. The code will halt, and then you can run the code one-step-at-a-time while monitoring the variables.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ for my IDE and the console doesn't have any output, no errors no nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much Old Dog! I used the debugger for the first time ever and it showed that the course English didn't receive any grades that were inputted. I went and checked it out and I had this code as if else statements:

if (gradeMathCheckBox.isSelected()) { .... }
if (gradeEnglishCheckBox.isSelected()) { ..... }

Comment: I was working late last night and must have changed it because it was working just fine yesterday.